# Updating answers when a version changes

Tags: feature-request

I was searching how to fetch the pages liked by a user in facebook graph api , filtered by category . 
I have found many answers , suggesting the use of fql
But from vesion 2.1 of graph api, fql is deprecated . So I feel it would be better if those questions are answered again or a comment is added that this solution will not be working any more .
Can this be made possibe? also can the question be tagged as old or inactive?

Comment: Not everyone will be using the latest version, so "old" questions/answers can still be relevant to many searchers. You could post a new answer on an old question, saying how it could be done in a new version, or post comments pointing this out on existing questions/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel it would be better if those questions are answered again or a comment is added that this solution will not be working any more

Then go right ahead and do that.  Those are both perfectly fine ways of dealing with such a situation.

I see no need for any new features, given that you already have those capabilities.